# How to determine the number of elements scanned into an array- c proramming

Tags: c, arrays

How can I determine the number of elements in an array of scanned in data?
For example, say I have an array that looks like this:

```
    array[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Obviously I can count the number of elements in this array, but if I scan in a much larger array, I don't want to count the number of elements individually. How can I use code to find the number of elements?

Comment: Is this a statically-declared array or is it allocated dynamically using `malloc()`?

Comment: `int array[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}; size_t count = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);`

Comment: you can use sizeof function for this if it is allocated like above.

Comment: You'll have to clarify this quite a bit to get any good answers. Maybe post an example of the array declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
int numberofelements = sizeof(array)/sizeof(int) //using type of array as int
```

However this cannot be done inside a function as the array is passed to it as a pointer so sizeof(array) will return size of the pointer. 
Perform this calculation before calling any function